# Is there another alternative for android studio

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, mobile, android-virtual-device

I'm in a middle of a project in react native (expo), all of a sudden auto refresh stopped and I kept on getting some weird error, so  I, taught it was an update issue after updating Android Studio, it tool longer to load emulator. finally I deleted the avd and created a new one only to be stuck in black screen. I've tried all solution I found in stack overflow but no success.

I would like to know if there is any other application I can use as avd instead of Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

You can use genymotion as AVD
https://www.genymotion.com

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use physical device or you can mirror your device using Vysor - https://www.vysor.io/,
AVD alternative are

1. GenyMotion - https://www.genymotion.com
2. BlueStacks
3. AirDroid

Comment: Is it possible to use bluestack  or my physical device, please explain or do you have any link where I read more about it

Comment: Yes we can use Bluestack as it is similar to other virtual devices. For physical device may read this -> https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using expo I would recommend you to test the app on a physical device using the expo client (available on the Google play store)

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, I tried the expo web but my app looked like an alien compared to what it was when Android was working

Comment: thanks i found your solution useful, this helped <a href="https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device#method-1-using-adb-reverse-recommended>here</a> but is there a way to test my app while developing without external deveice

Comment: Yes you can always use Android Studio or if you have a Mac you can use TestFlight to simulate an ios device